# How to fix "Warning: useLayoutEffect does nothing on the server" while using Material UI and reactDOMServer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, warnings, react-dom-server

I'm having a issue with ReactDOMServer and Material UI Theme Provider.. Everything is working just **fine** but I keep getting this annoying error on console:

```
Warning: useLayoutEffect does nothing on the server, because its effect cannot be encoded into the server renderer's output format. This will lead to a mismatch between the initial, non-hydrated UI and the intended UI. To avoid this, useLayoutEffect should only be used in components that render exclusively on the client.
```

All the solutions I've found so far involve me having to remove ThemeProvider, but I would like to know if there is no way better to solve this?

**CODE:**

```
  const mapIcon = useMemo(() => {
    let namePosition: MapPinProps['namePosition'] = 'bottom-start';

    if (position.lng > 120) {
      namePosition = 'bottom-end';
    }

    if (position.lng > 120 && position.lat < -80) {
      namePosition = 'top-end';
    }

    if (position.lng <= 120 && position.lat < -80) {
      namePosition = 'top-start';
    }

    const html = ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(
      <ThemeProviders>
        <MapPin
          active={isMapBuilder ? active : !completed}
          highlight={highlightRequiredEvent}
          icon={completed && doneIcon ? doneIcon : icon}
          name={event?.type !== EVENTS_TYPE.ANIMATION || isMapBuilder ? name : ''}
          rarity={rarity}
          read={isMapBuilder || event?.type === EVENTS_TYPE.ANIMATION || read}
          interactive={isMapBuilder || event?.type !== EVENTS_TYPE.ANIMATION}
          selected={selected}
          shape={shape}
          size={iconSize}
          userSettings={user.settings}
          namePosition={namePosition}
          locked={locked && !isMapBuilder}
          isMapBuilder={isMapBuilder}
        />
      </ThemeProviders>
    );

    return new L.DivIcon({
      className: '',
      // iconAnchor,
      // popupAnchor,
      iconSize: [iconSize, iconSize],
      html: html.toString(),
    });
  }, [
    position.lng,
    position.lat,
    event?.type,
    isMapBuilder,
    active,
    completed,
    highlightRequiredEvent,
    doneIcon,
    icon,
    name,
    rarity,
    read,
    selected,
    shape,
    iconSize,
    user.settings,
    locked,
  ]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to give some options that could help on solving that. I'll make some assumptions here and there, allowing myself to be wrong in some cases.

#### Context

[`useLayoutEffect()` only fires after DOM mutations](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#uselayouteffect). In general, servers don't have a proper way of handling that. Also, the official doc also mentions:

> If you use server rendering, keep in mind that neither useLayoutEffect nor useEffect can run until the JavaScript is downloaded. This is why React warns when a server-rendered component contains useLayoutEffect.

and gives a way of fixing it but it requires access to the source code (which I suppose you don't have).

#### Assumptions

- You are using Server Side Rendering to build Components at the Backend
- You are also using React at the Client (Frontend)
- You are using Leaflet for Maps (because [L.DivIcon()](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#divicon))
- You don't have access to change the source code of the `<ThemeProviders />` component

#### Possible Solution #1 (Possibly best one?)

You could try to use [ReactDOMServer.renderToString()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html#rendertostring) instead of [ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html#rendertostaticmarkup).

Explanation: Supposing that you are using this on the server and using React on the Client, [according to the official docs about ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html#rendertostaticmarkup):

> If you plan to use React on the client to make the markup interactive, do not use this method. Instead, use [renderToString](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html#rendertostring) on the server and [ReactDOM.hydrateRoot()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-client.html#hydrateroot) on the client.

#### Possible Solution #2 (With access to `ThemeProviders` component source code)

You could change the check for the usage of `useLayoutEffect()` and prevent it from using it at the server, where you don't have any DOM.

Explanation: According to [this comment inside an Issue at GitHub](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/15798#issuecomment-495078241), it suggest choosing between `useLayoutEffect()` and `useEffect()` based on the existence of the DOM. The comment mention about using something like:

```js
const canUseDOM: boolean = !!(
  typeof window !== 'undefined' &&
  typeof window.document !== 'undefined' &&
  typeof window.document.createElement !== 'undefined'
);

const useIsomorphicLayoutEffect = canUseDOM ? useLayoutEffect : useEffect;
```

And you could use this `useIsomorphicLayoutEffect()` inside your component.

#### Possible Solution #3 (not use SSR)

You could consider removing the usage of the `ReactDOMServer`.

Explanation: This seems to be a very simple component and the cost of choosing to render it on Client could be insignificant compared to the server render. **NOTE:** Before choosing to remove the SSR you could base this decision on some benchmarks and tests.

---

I hope that some of this could help you!

Comment: I have a similar problem that throws the same error. I am using renderToString but it also throws the same error, so that doesn't seem to be a viable solution.

Comment: Did you try the other options? Also, maybe the OP will return and maybe it'll present us with a solution that could work.

Comment: I came here because I got the error with "renderToString". I don't know why this answer was accepted because 1) is wrong and 3) doesn't solve the problem -- you're just running away from it. 2) isn't possible if third party components use useLayoutEffect.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I'm supposing that OP went with the 3rd proposed solution, which you stated correctly: do not solve the original problem (using this lib at the server) but could be a solution for the implementation. If you are using the exact same lib with the same configs, **maybe it is not possible to use SSR for this** (but this is what I'm supposing). Could you provide a working running example so I could help you?